# Are HR/Recruiters worst affected by covid-19?

Tags: covid-19

Just was checking my LinkedIn, I see a lot of recruiters losing their jobs due to covid-19, is this true?
Are recruiters worst affected by covid-19?

Comment: "Checking my LinkedIn" - [recruiters made up a large proportion of the posts on LinkedIn pre-COVID as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias).

Comment: Keep in mind that recruiters also  both over-represented on LinkedIn AND know how to generate visibility on it. When is the last time you saw a post by a factory worker or cook or maid on LinkedIn like, ever?

Comment: Plus, HR is a LOT more than recruiting. The HR people I know personally have never worked so hard. They are the ones putting out those checklists of how to be safe in the office, or how to work from home, dealing with complaints and stress from management and workers, helping people who were temporary workers from another country, trying to find a way to get vital people across borders, establishing policies about things like paying for office chairs at home and so much more. They are way to busy to go on LinkedIn and complain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are recruiters worst effected by covid-19?

Not even close, those in the tourism, hospitality & service industries are by far the hardest hit. For countries relying on these industries the roll on affect is taking out many other industries as well.

HR are ducking and diving, but in my locale at least they have retained their positions.

Answer (score 2):

**Not the worst, but hit pretty hard**

I imagine that being a cruise ship entertainer has a far higher unemployment rate right now. However, yes, many are being hit quite hard. It is a combination of many of them being contract workers (and therefore the easiest to lay off) and many companies having absolutely no need for them for the next little while.

Plenty of companies are actively hiring through, at least for software engineers and business operations people, so lots of them are still on the job.